# What is the reason for the following error while I am calling a rest client in spring boot using rest template

Tags: spring, rest, post, spring-boot, resttemplate

My code snippet is here...

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    PinsDTO pinsDTO = new PinsDTO();
    pinsDTO.setPin(pin);
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity(pinsDTO, headers);

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.append("url");

    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI(url.toString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

    }
    String seskey = null;
    try {
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);

        ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();
        response = (ServiceResponse) responseEntity.getBody();
        if (response.specifiedCode.equals("202")) {
            seskey = "";
        } else if (response.specifiedCode.equals("406")) {

            seskey = "INVALID";

        } else if (response.specifiedCode.equals("400")) {
            seskey = "NO";
        }

    } catch (RestClientException rce) {
        rce.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my error....

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 406      at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:747)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:700)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:592)
>     at
>   lk.dialog.ccs.retailloan.ussd.model.RetailLoanUssdManager.pinValidate(RetailLoanUssdManager.java:786)
>     at
>   lk.dialog.ccs.retailloan.ussd.controller.RetailLoanUssdController.pinvalidation(RetailLoanUssdController.java:53)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the content type in your headers but you did not set the accept header. Apparently the service you are calling is returning with a non-implicit content type.

So find out what is that services content type and provide that in the client header config:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.xxx, MediaType.yyy));
```

Comment: I put this.   headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));    But this didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you found out what is the content type of server response?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was api side issue